# forms with multiple actions

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I have a form that adds a user to a mysql database (working) but I also need it to email the new user details to a certain email address (also working )

Problem is I cant set 2 form actions. Is there anyway to work around this? So when I click submit it will add the values to the mysql table and send the email.

My code:

add.php:

```
<?php
include('database.php');

if($_POST['action'])
{
  $name=$_POST['name'];
  $extension=$_POST['extension'];
  $department=$_POST['department'];
  $phone=$_POST['phone'];
  $email=$_POST['email'];

  $query="INSERT INTO users (ID, Name, Email, Extension, Phone, Department) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$email', '$extension', '$phone', '$department')";
  $rez=mysql_query($query);

header("Location: index.php");

 }
?> 
<style type="text/css">
<!--
form {  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, mono}
body {  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif}
-->
</style>


<form action="email.php" method="POST">
Name:<br><input type="text" name="name"><br />
Email:<br><input type="text" name="email"><br />
Extension:<br><input type="text" name="extension"><br />
Phone:<br><input type="text" name="phone"><br />
Department:<br> <select name ="department"
            <option value="ADMIN">ADMIN</option>
            <option value="AFTER-SALES DIRECTOR">AFTER-SALES DIRECTOR</option>
            <option value="ALPINE DEALER PRINCIPAL">ALPINE DEALER PRINCIPAL</option>
            <option value="AUTO ARMOUR/AUTO ENHANCE - FITMENT CENTRE (Smash and Grab)">AUTO ARMOUR/AUTO ENHANCE - FITMENT CENTRE (Smash and Grab)</option>
            <option value="BANDIT-VW">BANDIT-VW</option>
            <option value="BOOKINGS VW">BOOKINGS VW</option>
            <option value="DRIVEWAY/WASHBAYS">DRIVEWAY/WASHBAYS</option>
            <option value="FINANCE AND INSURANCE">FINANCE AND INSURANCE</option>
            <option value="IT DEPARTMENT">IT DEPARTMENT</option>
            <option value="MARKETING DEPARTMENT">MARKETING DEPARTMENT</option>
            <option value="MASTER CARS">MASTER CARS</option>
            <option value="MAYOR OF PINETOWN">MAYOR OF PINETOWN</option>
            <option value="NEW CAR PREP DEPARTMENT">NEW CAR PREP DEPARMENT</option> 
            <option value="NUMBER PLATES">NUMBER PLATES</option>
            <option value="PANELBEATER - EASIFIX - CAR CARE">PANELBEATER - EASIFIX - CAR CARE</option>
            <option value="PARTS">PARTS</option>
            <option value="PARTS DISPATCH">PARTS DISPATCH</option>
            <option value="PARTS TELESALES">PARTS TELLESALES</option>
            <option value="USED CAR PREP AND ORDERS">USED CAR PREP AND ORDERS</option>
            <option value="VW NEW CARS ADMIN AND STOCK CONTROL">VW NEW CARS ADMIN AND STOCK CONTROL</option>
            <option value="VW NEW VEHICLE SHOWROOM">VW NEW VEHICLE SHOWROOM</option>
            <option value="VW SERVICE ADVISORS">VW SERVICE ADVISORS</option>
            <option value="VW WORKSHOP">VW WORKSHOP</option>
            <option value="VW WORKSHOP FOREMEN">VW WORKSHOP FOREMEN</option>
            <option value="WARRANTY & CLAIMS">WARRANTY & CLAIMS</option>
            <option value="WORKSHOP DRIVERS">WORKSHOP DRIVERS</option>
    </select>
<br />
<br><input type="submit" name="action" value="Submit">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
<a href="index.php">Extension List</a>
```

mail.php:

```
<?php

$name                = $_POST['name'];
$email               = $_POST['email'];
$extension           = $_POST['extension'];
$phone               = $_POST['phone'];
$department          = $_POST['department'];

require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "****"; // SMTP server                     // enables
SMTP debug information 
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
$mail->SMTPSecure = false;
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Host       = "****"; // sets the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 587;                  
$mail->Username   = "****"; // SMTP account username
$mail->Password   = "****";        // SMTP account password
$mail->From = "****";
$mail->FromName = "Extension List";

$mail->addAddress('****', "");

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject  = 'New Extension Added';
$mail->Body     = "New User added to Extension List:" . "<br>" . "<br>" .  
"Name:" . $name . "<br>" . 
"Email Address:" . $email . "<br>" . 
"Extension Number:" . $extension . "<br>" . 
"Cell Number:" . $phone . "<br>" . 
"Department:" . $department;

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo 'Message could not be sent.';
echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
exit;
}
echo 'Email Sent Successfully!';
?>
```

Comment: Its simple, wherever you are saving user data, from that success function call, email sending function thats it. why you need two actions, everything you will do after saving user details.

Comment: Why don't you add the user and then send an email In the same page ? The user won't even see the email on your page. I made the exact same thing on a project, everything worked fine. Or maybe I am missing something ?

Comment: First, be careful with this unprepared SQL query! It is vulnerable to SQL injection, I would suggest you to use a prepared statement instead. 

Regarding your main question, you could either send one form via Ajax and javascript then the other one normally, or do `include('mail.php')` in your add.php if the user did post the form.

Comment: @Antony where would i put the include mail.php sir? (I apologise im still learning abit )

Comment: Right after `if($_POST['action']){`

Comment: Are `add.php` and `mail.php` in the same folder?

Comment: never mind sir @Antony i made a mistake the file is called email.php(not mail.php and i just had to add the ; at the end of include('email.php') its working perfectly thank you so much. If you want you can answer the question with that and il set it as correct. Thank you again

Comment: Glad it did help! Answer is now posted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, be careful with this unprepared SQL query! It is vulnerable to SQL injection, I would suggest you to use a prepared statement instead.

Regarding your main question, you could either :
Add `include('mail.php')` in your add.php right after the `if($_POST['action'])`
 condition. This will execute the content of mail.php if the form is executed, sending the email,
or
Send one form via Ajax and javascript then let the other one be sent as normal

Answer (score 0):

1. Use PDO prepared statements instead of the mysql functions. This is leaving you vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

Example:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.DATABASE_HOST.';dbname='.DATABASE_NAME, DATABASE_USERNAME, DATABASE_PASSWORD);
$stm = $pdo->prepare("insert into `phone` (`name`, `number`) values (:name, :number)");
$stm->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stm->bindParam(':number', $number);
$stm->execute();
```

2. Just cut the PHPmailer code and place it above the `header()` call. Then you can get rid of the duplicate variable initialization.